# how to allocate memory when initialising graph in C?

Tags: c, list, graph, malloc

I'm trying to learn graphs in C and at the moment I'm trying to write a function that initializes the graph with the given data structures. 
so the structures I have are:

```
typedef struct linked list{
 int index;
 struct linked list *next;
} List;

typedef struct {
 char *name;
 List *outlist;
 int outdegree;
} Node;

typedef struct {
 int maxSize;
 Node *table;
} Graph;
```

and i have three functions which are :

```
int initialise_graph(Graph *mygraph, int maxSize)
{
}

int insert_graph_node(Graph *mygraph, int n, char *name)
{
}

int insert_graph_link(Graph *mygraph, int source, int target)
{
}
```

I'm currently struggling with the first function. 
I know that I have to allocate memory for each data structure in the first function, but I don't know how to malloc the memory for each struct through the for loop. I appreciate it if someone could help me with that please.

Comment: _I'm currently struggling with the the first function..._: show the code your are struggling with, otherwise it's hard for us to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: You really cannot have spaces in symbol names (`struct linked list`) in C. Nor in most other programming languages.

Comment: Im trying to write the first function which is    int initialise_graph(Graph *mygraph, int maxSize)

Comment: @M.Asgari, yes we understand that you're trying to write the `initialise_graph` function. But please show us what you have written so far, even if it's wrong.

Comment: @MichaelWalz thanks for replying to me! i haven't written anything yet since i couldn't figure out how to start it!

Comment: @M.Asgari you forgot to mention what the return values of the functions represent.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm currently struggling with the first function. I know that I have to allocate memory for each data structure in the first function, but I don't know how to malloc the memory for each struct through the for loop

Since your Graph objects have a `maxSize` member and a single pointer to `Node` and `Node` has no links in it, the intent is clearly for you to allocate and initialise an array of nodes.

You'll need sensible values for all the unused nodes in your initially empty graph. I would suggest `NULL` for the name (not specified yet), `NULL` for the `outlist` (i.e. it is empty) and `0` for `outdegree`.

I would do this by calling calloc for the nodes which allocates space and zeros all the bytes in that space.

```
int initialise_graph(Graph *mygraph, int maxSize)
{
    mygraph->maxSize = maxSize;
    mygraph->table = calloc(maxSize, sizeof *table);
    return 0;
}
```

That's it, you are done.

However:

- you might want to put some code in to check that `table` is non null. Opinioins differ on this, normally I rely on the platform's memory protection to pick it up, but if you are in embedded world, that might not work.
- the above code is not strictly speaking portable since a `NULL` pointer need not be represented by a pattern of all zero bytes. If that concerns you, use a loop to initialise the nodes. (Omitting the NULL check again).

  ```
   mygraph->table = calloc(maxSize, sizeof *table);
   // Null check would go here
   for (i = 0 ; i < maxSize ; ++i)
   {
       table[i].name = NULL;
       table[i].outlist = NULL;
       table[i].outdegree = 0;
   }
  ```

Comment: thats a perfect answer, Thanks a lot ! would i need to follow the same strategy for the other 2 insert methods as well?

Comment: No, for insert_graph_node, you need to select an empty element in the table and fill in the details. For onsert_graph_link, you'll need to create a List object with malloc and add it to the relevant node.